How to avoid line breaks in function arguments when formatting code in python?
My work environment: vscode + flake8 + AutoFormat After save
flake8.args: --ignore=E501,F401,W292,E203,F403.
Now I'm facing this problem:
Before formatting:
parser.add_argument("--template",type=str,default=None,help="path of the template file, usually end with .jsonl")

After formatting:
parser.add_argument(
    "--template",
    type=str,
    default=None,
    help="path of the template file, usually end with .jsonl",
)

Every single argument in a separate line.
I'd prefer not to change lines. How can I fix this?
Thanks! :)
I tried add flake8.args
--max-line-length=1024.
It didn't work

Oh! I'm sorry for that many of the line breaks in the question do not print out. I hope you  can understand what i mean.

As I know, there is no specific configuration key for function params separating to multiple lines. You can turn them off at all (which disables every multiple line formatting case)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
